# How one did manage to create and access structures that behaved like arrays in C89?

Tags: c

Before C99 programmers were obliged to define all arrays with fixed sizes that were known at compile time. How did people manage to create and access structures that behaved like arrays but whose sizes were not known until runtime?

Comment: they used dark magic^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D^D `malloc( )`.

Comment: ANSI C programmers were never obliged to define all arrays with fixed sizes that were known at compile time, unless if by array you mean "array on the stack," in which case your question nearly answers itself.

Comment: Wasn't it C99 that allowed variable length arrays on the stack?

Comment: @Haz Oh, so it's not only me who remembers that. I'll edit this one as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the use of [`malloc(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/malloc.3.html) and [`free(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/free.3.html) to do dynamic memory management.  It's still done today.

```
void f(int n)
{
  int *nInts = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

  /* do stuff with 'nInts' */

  free(nInts);
}
```

Comment: Or `alloca()` and no `free()` :-D

Comment: Is this how variable-length arrays are typically implemented in C?

Comment: can you explain it a bit more please? :))

Comment: @templatetypedef Yes, it is. Or, since C99, you can have variable-length stack arrays as well.

Comment: @Vlad - good call, that's more analagous to a C99 VLA, too.  It is, however, non-standard.

Comment: The links to the man pages are about as simple of an explanation as you can get without examples.  If you need examples, look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/)

Comment: @CarlNorum: I've changed your man page links. Hope you don't mind. Please don't use die dot net if possible. It is the most brain dead web site with tons of outdated, non-reliable information that generates money through aggressive SEO. Here at SO many people are fighting this crap :)

Comment: @Vlad - no problem.  I didn't know that was a bad place to go.

Comment: what can happen if there is no memory in C99 VLA implementation? I know that `malloc()` returns NULL. But in the case of VLA an error message from operating system or something?

Comment: @Jack, you'd get a stack overflow, which could cause any number of bad problems.

Comment: @Jack: which is why VLAs aren't as useful as you might think.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to [this](http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html).

As said there, it's not really sure if it's legal or portable. That said I have seen code like this but never written it myself.